# Conditional formatting with multiple conditions for Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format cells that have a value of 500 or higher but only if column E in their row has the specific text value "Sup".

Comment: Several things mentioned in other conditional formatting questions but nothing worked. =AND(E3="Sup";A2>=500) was my last try

Comment: `Several things`- eleborate..`but nothing worked` - how exactly it's not working

Comment: `=AND(E3="Sup";A2>=500)` --> `=AND(E2="Sup";A2>=500)` for second row

Comment: That formula would work but your rows are out of sync, should (presumably) be E2 and A2.

Comment: The cells that can be and that are to be formatted >=500 are in columns J through to S.

Comment: With the current formula I am not seeing any formatting. The formatted range is A1:X100 and the format is a brightly colored fill so I didn't forget to set that.

Comment: Right now =AND(E2="Sup";L2>=500) is being applied to =$J$2:$S$2 but it is not coloring cell L2, which is the one with the value of 500, but J2.

Comment: use `=AND($E2="Sup";$L2>=500)`

Comment: Now it is formatting whole rows and not just the cell that has the value >=500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=AND($E1="Sup",J1>=500)
```

with colour of our choice and range for Applies to of =$J$1:$S$x, where `x` is the highest row number where the CF is to apply.

Comment: Changed the comma to a semicolon in the formula and J1 to J in the range and it worked.

Comment: Alright, nevermind my mention of the comma then. And thanks for the tip on selecting the range first.